# Do Oracles of Ages & Seasons play in Game Boy Color mode or Game Boy Advance mode on the 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-oracle-of-seasons, zelda-oracle-of-ages

In the original release for *The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Ages* and *The Legend of Zelda: Oracle of Seasons* the games supported some extra content when played on a Game Boy Advance. Is that the case with the downloadable versions for the 3DS as well?

Comment: I know it can be found easily with a little bit of googling, but I thought I should provide [A Link to the Past](http://zeldawiki.org/Advance_Shop) (pun intended), for anyone who's wondering what the extra content for the GBA is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 3DS version is the original GameBoy Color version (so it's missing the Advanced Shop, but you can edit your saves to add in the exclusive rings).

All of the colouring tweaks found in the Advance version are also missing.

GBA with the Advance shop open on the left. 3DS Virtual Console version on the right.
[image: GBA with the Advance shop open on the left. 3DS Virtual Console version on the right.]

Answer (score 2):

From various posts found on GameFAQs ([example](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/66317408), [another example](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997614-nintendo-3ds/65813162)), I think you can assume that the Advance Shop is unfortunately missing in both Oracle of Ages and Oracle of Seasons.

I did not find any official source yet, but there is a sufficient amount of people on the internet complaining about it to be sure that they are missing.